# Not able to setup Umbraco in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to setup Umbraco in Visual Studio 2012 with Nuget package. After package installation when I try to run it getting following exception.

***Type is not resolved for member 'Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity,Umbraco.Core, Version=1.0.5261.28127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.***
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity,Umbraco.Core, Version=1.0.5261.28127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using nuget for Umbraco. Using a CMS like that, you won't want to update through nuget once you're in production. Best keep it manually. Here is a step by step to get setup in VS with Umbraco.

1. Open Visual Studio, create a new "ASP.NET Empty Web Application", with a folder for the solution. Here is how I set it up:

   - C:\_Websites\[MyProject] --> All this in source control
   - C:\_Websites\[MyProject]\Website --> .sln file is here
   - C:\_Websites\[MyProject]\Website\[MyProject] --> .csproj and /bin are here
2. Download the version of Umbraco you want from here: http://our.umbraco.org/download
3. Unzip that folder and place it in that [MyProject] folder
4. Once this is in place, setup your hosts file 127.0.0.1 myproject.local
5. Setup a new website in IIS, set the binding, make sure the app. pool is using framework 4
6. Back in Visual Studio, click Show All Files in the Solution explorer and refresh. Include everything in your project.
7. Build solution and run the website using myproject.local, should be good to go!

I like this setup because Umbraco is developer oriented and this way I control everything. I have to add the references I need manually and this makes me more familiar with the platform as I work with it.

I know I'm not helping you with you problem directly, but this is the setup I use and I never have issues with this. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using VS Development Server - try running the program as administrator after selecting "Local IIS Web Server" in the Web section your project properties as explained [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/46347-Error-after-running-Umbraco-on-Debug-mode-in-vs2010-after-installed-via-Nuget).

Comment: thanks @kml09k: Last year we end up using Sitefinity (as it looks much better as compare to Umbraco). And then we install with Web Matrix. I will remember this in-case I need to use umbraco in future.